# What can I do to resolve the "ModuleError: No module named 'new'" problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, libraries

I am trying to run a program but then I get an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\mmv456\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
  exec(line)
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'new'
```

I tried finding this site.py file in that directory but it isn't there so I can't see what exactly is the problem within the python file. I appreciate any help with this.

EDIT: Adding code:

```
import collections
import itertools
import sys

if sys.platform == 'cli':
    import System
    CPU_COUNT = System.Environment.ProcessorCount
else:
    #try:
    #    import multiprocessing
    #    CPU_COUNT = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    #except ImportError:
    #    CPU_COUNT = 1

    # IronPython seems to be the only common Python implementation that   doesn't
    # have a GIL and therefore the only implementation that benefits from this.
    # Therefore, don't bother making any threads on other implementations.
CPU_COUNT = 1

try:
    import thread
    import threading
except ImportError:
    import dummy_threading as threading
    import _dummy_thread as thread
    CPU_COUNT = 1
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'new' this line means that you have error in your importings. Try correcting your import modul names.

Comment: Hey, I just added my code. So you're saying that some import line doesn't have the correct library?

Comment: You have issue with your python File "C:\Users\mmv456\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
  exec(line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'new'` this line means that you have an error in your imports.

When I run the code you just posted it runs perfectly, but if I add import new it give exact error as you had:

```
import collections
import itertools
import sys
import new # I just added

if sys.platform == 'cli':
    import System
    CPU_COUNT = System.Environment.ProcessorCount
else:
    #try:
    #    import multiprocessing
    #    CPU_COUNT = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    #except ImportError:
    #    CPU_COUNT = 1

    # IronPython seems to be the only common Python implementation that   doesn't
    # have a GIL and therefore the only implementation that benefits from this.
    # Therefore, don't bother making any threads on other implementations.
CPU_COUNT = 1

try:
    import thread
    import threading
except ImportError:
    import dummy_threading as threading
    import _dummy_thread as thread
    CPU_COUNT = 1
```

Error:

```
(python37) C:\Users\Documents>py test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 685, in <module>
    import new
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'new'
```

But the thing is my error is in `test.py` but your is pointing to `site.py` which is in python lib. Which means you have something wrong going in your python environment. Even there is similar [issues](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/2038) around the world.

> Simple solution is uninstalling and reinstalling your python
>   environment.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try working on the python environment and see what I can do.